# Error: "Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected" Please help me to solve this error below i've also given the code

Tags: android, android-studio

package com

import android.content.Intent import android.os.Build import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity import android.os.Bundle import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi import com.example.sendit.MainActivity import com.example.sendit.R import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sign_in.*

class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() { @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M) override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in) btnSignUp.setOnContextClickListener { val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java) startActivity(intent)}

```
btnLogin.setOnContextClickListener {
    val regIntent = Intent(this,Log_inActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(regIntent)
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Definition of OnContextClickListener:

```
/**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is context clicked.
     */
    public interface OnContextClickListener {
        /**
         * Called when a view is context clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that has been context clicked.
         * @return true if the callback consumed the context click, false otherwise.
         */
        boolean onContextClick(View v);
    }
```

The method `onContextClick` must return boolean value by signature. In your code snippet last line of lambda passed to `setOnContextClickListener` returns `Unit` type because `startActivity` return `void` by declaration.
That's why just return `true` (lambda in kotlin uses value retuned by last instruction as return value when her return type not a Unit or void in java terms):

```
btnLogin.setOnContextClickListener {
    val regIntent = Intent(this,Log_inActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(regIntent)
    true
}
```